# How can I get the image name when selecting an image

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working with images for the first time and I have been able to select an image and display it on the page. My question is how can I get the name of the image selected ? I been searching around but have not been able to find it . This code below fires every time you select an image

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {

        photoImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        let FileName = " Image Name of selected file"
    }
```

where the photoImageView is

```
var photoImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 82,y: 300,width: 100,height: 100))
```

a small ImageView that displays the selected image, I would like to get the FileName now any suggestions would be great

Comment: Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uiimagepickercontroller+image+name) before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. The system doesn't give you the user's name for the file. I remember puzzling about this as well.

As I recall what it gives you is a pointer to an in-memory UIImage object, not even a URL to a system-named file on disk. (But it's been a while since I've used the image picker.)

Comment: Not quite. You can get the URL for an image selected from the photo library. That URL will of course have a filename as part of the URL. It's not really a meaningful filename but you can get it if really needed.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for the correction. I couldn't remember for sure. In any case you can't get a *meaningful* filename...

Answer (score 0):

Using `Photos` API (`PHAsset` & `PHAssetResource`) you can get file name of the image selected using `UIImagePickerController`. I posted the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627901/how-to-get-file-name-in-uiimagepickercontroller-with-asset-library).

Comment: But is it the user's name or some arbitrary filename?

Comment: @DuncanC It's an arbitrary name assigned by the operating system, e.g. IMG_xxxx.JPG

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 11.0 onwards they introduced a new key into info dictionary to get PHAsset of picked image , you can try this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
if let photoAsset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset {
  if let fileName = photoAsset.value(forKey: "filename") ?? "nonamefound"}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use write this code in your delegate function for fetching the image name from the picker.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : 
Any]) {
   
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
        if let imgUrl = info[.imageURL] as? URL {
            let fileName = imgUrl.lastPathComponent
            print(fileName)
        }
    }
```