# convert mediaURL to PHAsset

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, phasset

I am using UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to record a video and then open it in one of my arrays which is [PhAsset] type. I can't do it as can't find anything for converting to phasset from mediaURL.

```
extension EditViewController : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL //as? phAsset doesn't work

print("Video URL === \(videoURL)") //VideoURL of the recorded Video

//Need to append the video url into the last position of the array

self.newVideos.append(videoURL) // [PhAsset type array]
```

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627901/how-to-get-file-name-in-uiimagepickercontroller-with-asset-library

Comment: tried but can't help :(